# Complex SQL query - need to show random set of tuples against an expression

Tags: mysql, sql

Heres the scene I have the following tagble:

COMPANIES

```
|ID|NAME       |COUNTRY
=======================
|1 |ABC Company|AF
|2 |ADC Company|AG
|3 |WEC Company|AG
|4 |ABC Company|BR
|5 |DBC Company|FR
|6 |AZC Company|CR
|7 |AQC Company|AF
|8 |DBC Company|BR
|9 |AMI Company|IN
|10|CMI Company|CI
|11|ZMI Company|CN
```

I need to set up a query which returns a list of coompanies such that it shows a random 3 companies in each country ordered by the country i.e something like:

```
|ID|NAME       |COUNTRY
=======================
|13|ABC Company|AF
|71|AQC Company|AF
|25|ADC Company|AF
|54|DBC Company|AG
|32|WEC Company|AG
|41|ABC Company|AG
|64|AZC Company|CR
|85|DBC Company|CR
|91|AMI Company|CR
```

Comment: Fuzzy idea: A subquery using *ORDER BY RAND()* and *LIMIT 3* could be a start.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dense rank first or dense rank last

visit http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

look at some of the queries it would be clear how to use it

Comment: That is hardly helpful in a question about MySQL.